Reciting Birkat Shehechiyanu when purchasing a gun
Came across the article below, discussing if Shehecheyanu can be recited when a gun is purchased:

האם לברך "שהחיינו" בקניית אקדח?
מאת: נח זבולוני
האם רכישת נשק אישי כמו אקדח, מחייבת את ברכת "שהחיינו", בדומה לקונה בגד
חדש או כלים חדשים?
על מדוכה הלכתית זו ישבו בבית המדרש של "עטרת כוהנים", ישיבה שהוקמה
ברובע המוסלמי של העיר העתיקה בירושלים ועומדת תחת חסותו של ח"כ אריק
שרון.
בעקבות חתימת הסכם העקרונות בין ישראל לאש"ף, צוברים אנשי הימין בשטחים
נשק מכל הבא ליד, והועלתה השאלה האם יש לברך "שהחיינו" על רכישת אקדח.
שלושת רבני הישיבה הביעו את דעתם בשאלה הלכתית זו.
לפי ההלכה, "מי שבנה בית חדש או קנה כלים חדשים מברך שהחיינו". מה דינו
של אקדח, האם הוא דבר מעציב שגורם שפיכת דמים ואין לברך עליו, או דבר
משמח כמו קניית בגד חדש או כלים חדשים.
הרב שלמה אבינר, ראש הישיבה ותושב בית אל פסק חד וחלק שיש לברך. עמיתו,
הרב דוד כהן סבור כי כל נשק במהותם שייכים להרגשה מעורבת והם אינם בגדר
שאר הכלים לגבי ברכת "שהחיינו".
הרב אבי רונצקי סובר שאין בכלי הנשק שימוש יצירתי חיובי ואינו מוסיף לאדם
ולחברה דבר, אלא מונע היזק בלבד ולכן אין לברך "שהחיינו". בנוסף לכך,
אומר הרב: "איך אפשר לברך על רכישת כלי נשק ברכת "שהחיינו וקיימנו והגענו
לזמן הזה "? איזו שמחה זו? בעת שאנו נאלצים להלך חמושים, אין לברך
"שהחיינו".

I am looking for :

written material about this by the rabbis mentioned in the article (Rabbi Aviner, Rabbi Cohen and Rabbi Runetzky)
any other sources that discussed this topic


To address your first point:
Rav Shlomo Aviner (שאילת שלמה ח״ג פז) goes to great lengths to prove that one should make the Bracha of Shehechiyanu on purchasing a weapon for self-defense since we thankfully live in a generation that Jews can defend ourselves. This fact alone, he argues, is a cause for celebration.
Link used: https://raelblumenthal.org/lets-talk-about-guns
In שו"ת כחיצים ביד גיבור ח"א עמ' 127-133, it quotes that according to Rabbi Runetzky and Rabbi Cohen one does not say shehchinau on a gun, however, Rav Shlomo Aviner says one does.
To address the second point: People bring up many sources to say why one shouldn't say shehchianu on a gun.

The Ketzot Hashulchan 64:3, Magen Avraham 223:5, Kaf Hachaim 223:20, Yalkut Yosef Brachot Siman 223:1, and others say one doesn't say shehchinau on כלים.

In Shulchan Aruch Yoreah Deah Siman 28:2 the Rema says we shouldn't say shehchianu on the shechitah because its mazik, so many want to say the same by the gun.



Great answer! I wonder if he could say it on the holster (technically a kind of beged) to get out of the safek
